# Gatsby Static Image(gatsby-plugin-image) inside MDX

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby

Recently I have started working with Gatsby and right now I'm trying things with MDX, In my MDX file i can work with Gatsby Image throught GraphQL, but I want to use Static Image from gatsby-plugin-image and I'm getting errors like this:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2557 Image not loaded
> https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597305877032-0668b3c6413a?w=1300

When i try to implement this image inside .tsx it works so I'm wondering if it is possible or not.

**gatsby-config**

```
 "gatsby-remark-images",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
      options: {
        defaultLayouts: {
          default: require.resolve("./src/components/common/Layout.tsx")
        },
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
      __key: "images",
    },
```

Then in test.mdx I'm trying to use Static Image like this:

```
<StaticImage
    src={'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597305877032-0668b3c6413a?w=1300'}
    alt={''}
    width={3840}
    height={1000}
    layout={'constrained'}
/>
```

Comment: Can you share the full `test.mdx`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu https://prnt.sc/11x2tca only this code. Static Image is passed into MDXProvider

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `gatsby-plugin-image` directly in an MDX document. [This post on the Gatsby blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/mdx-embedded-gatsby-image/) explains how to use it indirectly by passing in image reference props via your Frontmatter.

Personally I've been able to do it like so:

*This example only loads local images, refer to the blog post for how to reference remote ones as it's more complex.*

**Template Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const Game = ({ data }) => {
  const { mdx } = data;
  const { frontmatter, body } = mdx;
  return (
    <Layout title={frontmatter.title}>
      <span className="date">{frontmatter.date}</span>
      <MDXRenderer localImages={frontmatter.embeddedImagesLocal}>
        {body}
      </MDXRenderer>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    mdx(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      slug
      body
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        title
        embeddedImagesLocal {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default Game;
```

**MDX Document**

```
---
title: Death Stranding
author: Hideo Kojima
date: 2021-05-06
template: game
embeddedImagesLocal:
  - '../images/20210513035720_1.jpg'
---

import { getImage, GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

A great game from Hideo Kojima.

<GatsbyImage alt='Sam in a destroyed mall' image={getImage(props.localImages[0])} />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`gatsby-remark-images`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images) plugin with `gatsby-plugin-mdx` and it handles the images for you.

Install the plugin, then in `gatsby-config.js`, update the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` to something like this:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
  options: {
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 900,
        },
      },
    ],
    plugins: [`gatsby-remark-images`]
  },
},
```

Then images work as expected using the `![alt](url)` markdown format.

Unfortunately the `maxWidth` is fixed across the site which wasn't ideal for me. I'm using the [@bonobolabs/gatsby-remark-images-custom-widths](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@bonobolabs/gatsby-remark-images-custom-widths/) fork which lets you specify the image width in the MDX file with an HTML style `img` tag:

```
<img src="./image.jpg" alt="My image" width="500px"/>
```

I believe it's only 'width' that is the extra property this gives you.